# Using GGNFS on CYGWIN for finding prime factors

Tags: cygwin, prime-factoring

I need to find the prime factors of a 94 digit. I found on the internet this [Link](http://gilchrist.ca/jeff/factoring/nfs_beginners_guide_perl.html) which is suppose to be a guidance for beginners to do the job. I couldn't get to pass Step2.

Anyway, my problem is I don't know how to use GGNFS with either windows or CYGWIN? I downloaded the required files but I don't know how to execute the code.

I downloaded the GGNFS from [HERE](http://gilchrist.ca/jeff/factoring/index.html). The details of the file that I downloaded are:

Type------Processor----Version----Size--------File---------------------------------Date

32bit-------x86-----------SVN 413----4.0 MB---ggnfs-svn413-win32-p4.zip-----03/20/2011

Your help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using [Dario Alpern's factoring applet](http://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM) to factor your 94-digit number? If not, try that, then come back here with more questions. [Jeff Gilchrist's instructions](http://gilchrist.ca/jeff/factoring/nfs_beginners_guide_perl.html) are pretty clear, but GGNFS isn't something that you can just plug in and run.

Comment: I tried this one and it took more than 3 weeks til my laptop stopped working until I had to do restart my computer and start over again.

Comment: Jeff's instructions are clear but I don't get what I'm suppose to. For example, right now i'm stuck at stage3. 

I created the example.n file with n:XXXX where XXXX are the 94 digits that I want to factor. 

Then, when I do (../factMsieve.pl example.n) in CYGWIN I get this
 message "-bash: ../factMsieve.pl: No such file or directory"

Comment: Then you need QS or NFS. Have you followed the instructions in Step 1? Exactly what step is causing you problems?

Comment: Use a single dot: ./factMsieve.pl example.n.

Comment: Step1 is to download the required software. I downloaded the source code from the link stated above. I also downloaded CYGWIN with PERL as a package to be installed. (For this I don't know how to make sure that PERL was installed). In step2, I did everything as required. I tried to do it from the windows command prompt and I got this error:

Comment: `
D:\cygwin\home\admin\g4_win>factMsieve.pl example.n
-> ___________________________________________________________
-> |        This is the factMsieve.pl script for GGNFS.       |
-> | This program is copyright 2004, Chris Monico, and subject|
-> | to the terms of the GNU General Public License version 2.|
-> |__________________________________________________________|
-> This is client 1 of 1
-> Using 1 threads
-> Working with NAME=example...
-> Error: poly file specifies degree 5 but highest poly
->   coefficient given is c0!
`
<code>

Comment: From the error message it is clear that perl has been installed. I am not a user of GGNFS so I can do little more to help. The basic idea is the program runs in three steps: polynomial selection, sieving, linear algebra. The error message shows you are stuck in polynomial selection. Perhaps the polynomial selection working file is corrupt; delete it and restart. What happens?

Comment: I deleted the example.poly but I got this message: 
-> Error: Polynomial file example.poly does not exist!
Cannot find example.poly

<br>

Comment: Ok, I think I was downloading so many files. The steps are clear but a bit confusing. I got it to work now by using ./factmsieve.pl example.n before I had 2 dots. I'm waiting now for the PolySelect to finish and go from there.

Comment: Good for you! Let me know when you get an answer.

Comment: After waiting for 5 days, I got the following message: 
-> Lattice sieving algebraic q-values from q=33600001 to 33660000.
-> ./factmsieve.pl : Severe error!
->     Current special q=33600001 has exceeded max. large alg. prime = 33554432                                                                                                     !
-> You can try increasing LPBA, re-launch this script and cross your fingers.
-> But be aware that if you're seeing this, your factorization is taking
-> much longer than it would have with better parameters.
Does anyone know what to do in this case?

Comment: Problem solved.. My problem was with the Msieve.exe file. I just downloaded Msieve.exe 1.50 and replaced it with the one in the bin folder. After 5 hours I got the factors.